# Mac OSX Android Studo: Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher

Tags: android, macos, cordova, ionic-framework

I've been doing some research on this issue, which has been asked on StackOverflow many times, yet all previous answers tend to dismiss the question with something like "Set the environment variables."

I just downloaded Android Studio to my Mac. I'm trying to get it to import a Cordova/Ionic app, but I get this error:

```
No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.
```

I figured I would follow the advice here:

https://gist.github.com/patrickhammond/4ddbe49a67e5eb1b9c03

and run:

```
 brew install ant
 brew install maven
 brew install gradle
 brew install android-sdk
 brew install android-ndk
```

but some of these packages have been moved, so I had to follow the advice here:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/11656

```
brew tap caskroom/cask
```

and then:

```
brew cask install android-sdk
brew cask install android-ndk
brew cask install android-platform-tools
```

This command:

```
 brew cask install android-ndk
```

offered this tip:

```
==> Caveats
You may want to add to your profile:
'export ANDROID_NDK_HOME="/usr/local/share/android-ndk"'
```

If I do this:

```
 ls -al /usr/local/share/android-ndk
```

I see:

```
 lrwxr-xr-x  /usr/local/share/android-ndk -> /usr/local/Caskroom/android-ndk/16b/android-ndk-r16b
```

I check both paths to be sure both are owned by me, as user.

I open

```
~/.bash_profile
```

and put this in place:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/local/share/android-sdk"
export ANDROID_NDK_HOME="/usr/local/share/android-ndk"

export PATH=$PATH:ANDROID_NDK_HOME:$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/
```

And then:

```
 source ~/.bash_profile
```

I open Android Studio again, and again I get the same error:

```
No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.
```

I open `Preferences` in Android Studio and, under `Path Variables` I add:

```
 ANDROID_HOME

 /usr/local/share/android-sdk
```

I restart Android Studio.

I get the same error as before.

What might I be doing wrong?

If I do this:

```
sdkmanager --list
```

I see:

```
Available Updates:
  ID      | Installed | Available
  ------- | -------   | -------  
  tools   | 26.0.1    | 26.1.1
```

[image]

Comment: Please make your question clear and readable (at the end) We like detail, we **really like what you want us to do for you** Concise, to the point (with examples if it can be done). What is wrong, how can we fix it for you ? build tools are now automatic if your up-todate, are you ?

Comment: you seemed to have installed everything you need **except** for the build tools! I don't use Mac but if `brew install android-sdk` worked I suppose `brew install android-build-tools` or something similar would

Comment: Chisko, I don't know what you mean. The SDK contains the build tools.

Comment: Jon Goodwin, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Something is wrong with your “tools” because the latest Tool is 27.1.0 (and now there’s a 28.0.0preview). So Instead of using “brew” (what do you need a package manager for?) just download Android studio 3.1.1, and go to SDK Manager and install everything from inside Android Studio. The rest? Is your “Cordova” project’s problem.

Comment: @Martin Marconcini -- I've uploaded an image. When I look in Android Studio Preferences it seems to show version 27 of the SDK. But I still get the error "no build tools installed"